# Compare accuracy between tools using k-fold cross validation, each tool is tested with different k values

Tags: classification, cross-validation, accuracy, supervised-learning

I'm working on a new way to do the classification in a supervised way and I want to compare its accuracy to some related works. These works are using the same data set and they are testing their accuracy, using k-fold cross-validation. Each one is using different k values and numbers of iterations.

My question is, can I do the comparison between their accuracy even if they are using different parameters of cross-validation? If no, what is the easiest way to compare without re-programming the latter works and re-doing the tests?